# Why doesn't vue build?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

There is a VUE + SSR application
When building an application, such an error appears,

> ERROR in 0.bf6d549e19d60bc5269e.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (Node) [0.bf6d549e19d60bc5269e.js:1471,6]

As far as I understand, the problem is related to UglifyJs
But how to fix, I can not understand (

My [package.json](https://hastebin.com/mosukivabo.json)

Webpack [config](https://hastebin.com/sumolojado.js)

and my `babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```